# Is it better to make 1 query or many queries to postgresql?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I got DB class which handles all these cursors, connections etc. And I got 3 methods:

return_all_records:
    `(SELECT * FROM TABLE)`

count_of_records:
    `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE)`

and return_record_by_pk:
    `(SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE pk=?)`

I should take each row and make operations with data. Is it better to make 1 big query to db or many small queries?

PS. I have got really many records in db. Smth like 10^8.
It's not really easy to receive them an once

```
for record in DB.return_all_records(): # 1 big query
     #code

for pk in range(DB.count_of_records()):
    DB.return_record_by_pk(pk) #small queries
```

Comment: I can't figure out exactly where the multiple queries are, but the answer is that in general, you want to avoid making many unnecessary calls to the database.  Sometimes, you can't avoid it, but you should try to avoid it.

Comment: I have got really many records in db

Comment: Please show us samples for the _actual_ queries you are running.

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not really easy to receive them a[t] once"? Does your code crash because you are using too much memory? Does it take longer than you expect?

Comment: They are in brackets near methods

Comment: It takes much time and memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much depends on the underlying database driver how this is handled. Instead of fetching all records at once, you should/can consider limiting the amount of rows returned using a `where` condition on the SQL to specify you "start row" and "end row". You can then slide e.g. 2000 rows at a time over your data. Please make sure to sort the data using an `order by` as otherwise the returned data will/can vary. Depending on the database you are using, the "limit" has different syntax (e.g. `rownum` in Oracle, a combination of `limit` and `offset` when using MySQL, ...). Depending on the column you use for sorting (and if it's indexed or not), the sorting can have a huge impact on the execution times and fetching "windows" from the middle or end of the table might be getting slow